# MCR (MATLAB Compiler Runtime) undefinedVarOrClass error on Windows 7

Tags: matlab, compiler-construction, runtime

I'm trying to execute an exe program that calls a dll compiled with MATLAB, I am using MATLAB MCR R2012b to execute it.

It works OK on Windows XP 32 bits, but when trying to run it on Windows 7 (64 bits) the following error raises:

```
Warning: Initializing Handle Graphics failed in matlabrc
This indicates a potentially serious problem in your MATLAB setup,
which should be resolved as soon as possible. Error detected was:
MATLAB:undefinedVarOrClass
Undefined variable "graphics" or class "graphics.internal.initializeMATLABRoot".
Warning: Failed to add default profiler filters.
>In matlabrc at 163
Undefined function 'javaaddpath' for input arguments of type 'cell'
Could not initialize function.
```

I have installed MCR R2012b for 32 bits, and JRE for 32 bits. I have tried changing the MATLAB_JAVA and the MATLAB_PREFDIR environment variables, with no results.

Also, I cannot try to execute the restoredfaultpath command because I just have MCR installed and not the complete MATLAB tool.

Can anyone provide any clue?

Comment: What is the argument you are passing to `javaaddpath`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not call directly to javaaddpath, the error araises in the file matlabrc, that is a matlab file. I think it's a problem of java or matlab installation more than a code problem.¡, in fact, it's working OK  on a Windows XP 64 bits system.